# Error installing R packages (R 3.4.4), asks for usethis when already installed

Tags: r, r-package, r-usethis

I'm having the following problem:
When I try to install **any** R package, at first it downloads the package just fine into a temporal location, and then the following error message appears:

Error: package ‘usethis’ required by ‘devtools’ could not be found
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘lattice’ had non-zero exit status

The wierd part of this is that package usethis is installed and loaded.

Any advise on what can be happening here? I'm a lost there..

[image: Image of the process (load usethis, install a package)]

Comment: Your R version is three years old, you may want to update first to R4.0.3!

Comment: There is something you are not telling us. install.packages() does not need devtools.

Comment: Mmmm.. I don't know, I'm using packrat but this should not affect the outcome of install.packages()..

Comment: I think your libraries got mixed up. You should try installing devtools first. I'm also wondering why you are trying to install lattice. Recommended packages should be part of your R installation.

Comment: Installing lattice was just an example, it fails with any package.
When I try to install devtools I get the same error..

Error: package ‘usethis’ required by ‘devtools’ could not be found
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Well, I have no experience with packrat but I believe it's at the core of your issue, probably in conjunction with your extremely outdated R version. I suspect that a package in the large dependency tree of usethis requires a newer R version.